# Chaquopy How can I import pattern library?

Tags: java, python, kotlin, design-patterns, chaquopy

I would like to import pattern library of python.
The build gradle (app) is like below.

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.chaquo.python'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chaquopy"
        python{
            pip{
                install "pattern"
            }
        }
        sourceSets{
            main{
                python{
                    srcDirs = ["src/main/python"]
                }
            }
        }
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }

        // Here is local python.exe folder.
        python{
            buildPython "C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Sync task finished successfully,
but it failed when I build the project, because of the failure to install mysqlclient.

[image: error image]

Can I import pattern library using Chaquopy?
I'll appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Pattern doesn't actually require mysqlclient: in fact, it defaults to using SQLite. So you can modify it to remove the requirement:

- Download the sdist from https://pypi.org/project/Pattern/#files.
- Extract it.
- Edit Pattern-3.6/setup.py to remove the "mysqlclient" requirement.
- Create a .zip or .tar.gz file from the modified Pattern-3.6 directory.
- Install this file by its filename, as shown in the [Chaquopy documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#requirements).

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot.